# field 'params' with an expando object in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

I have the following in C#:

```
dynamic JsonObject = new ExpandoObject();
JsonObject.action       = Action;
JsonObject.arguments    = JsonArguments;
JsonObject.id           = Id;
JsonObject.sig          = Signature;
var Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonObject);
```

and I need to change:

```
JsonObject.arguments = JsonArguments;
```

into:

```
JsonObject.params = JsonArguments;
```

but I can't use *params* as a field name with an expando object.

What would be a good workaround to build that json?

It's to use with deribit.com. They've released API V2 and changed some of the names, but I guess didn't think about that case.

Comment: [@params](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OGA9vl)?

Comment: @Selvin: I didn't know that syntax! it works perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: [point 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

Comment: I knew its use for strings, but I had no idea it could be used for other things, very nice to know!

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the expando into a dictionary or use a dictionary directly, for sample:

```
var jsonObject = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

jsonObject.Add("action", Action);
jsonObject.Add("params", JsonArguments);
jsonObject.Add("id", Id);
jsonObject.Add("sig", Signature);    

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonObject);
```

Comment: this would work, but Selvin's solution is much simpler

Comment: Dictionary would be fine in a dynamic scenario, where you have keys in an array for sample. But, ok, glad to help (if I help) anyway.